# Does python's GIL prevent parallel execution in a functionally separate c++ library?

Tags: python, c++, gil

I planning to write a python script that utilizes some multi-threaded c++ code I'm working on. The c++ code will not modify any values in the python runtime. Will python's global interpreter lock prevent the threads in the c++ code from executing in parallel? If so, what are some good resources to understand how to get around this?

The python script will only call an interface exposed by the c++ code: `void notify_btn_pressed(int btn_id)`. Python and the c++ code will have no other interaction.

Comment: in short answer, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GIL is a Python *Interpreter* lock. The Python bytecode interpreter doesn't know what your C++ library is doing behind the scenes. It doesn't have any way to prevent your C++ code from creating additional threads and doesn't attempt to prevent you from doing that.

Here is some [background on the GIL and native code](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads) that explains this. And here is [more general information about the GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock). These references are for Python 3.x, but Python 2.x works the same way. You can change the `3` to `2` in the URLs to see the corresponding (and nearly identical) Python 2.x docs.